# Refresh Activity after AlertDialog from ArrayAdapter is called

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

I call my specific `ArrayAdapter` from an `Activity` which shows a list of datasets from my database. If the user tap on an item of the `ArrayAdapter` it will open an extension of an `AlertDialog`. If the user taps on a button in this `AlertDialog` a dataset in the database will be deleted among others and the `AlertDialog` is `dismiss()`. Now I want to refresh the view of the `ArrayAdapter`.

I found solutions like

```
remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But where could I call this? Can I pass a boolean from the `AlertDialog` backwards to the `ArrayAdapter` if the user clicked on the specific button to say "hey adapter, please remove the current item in your list"?

here's some code:

Activity:

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
DBhandler db = new DBhandler (context);
list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context, db.getMyItems()))
```

MyAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(row != null) {
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(context, currentItem);
                myDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyDialog:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button btn_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DBhandler db = new DBhandler (context);
            db.delete(currentItem);
            Toast.makeText(context, "item is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

I found also [Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents), but I don't know how I can use that for my AlertDialog...

Answer (score 0):

You may call function of your custom adapter before dismissing alert dialog as

```
if(adapter.remove(postion)){
    adapter.refreshdata();
}
```

and the function like

```
public boolean removedata(int position){
     boolean isremoved = false;
    // loop array data and remove specific item
  //  and return isRemoved value.
    }
public void refreshdata(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand... where should I call the methods? I don't have an adapter instance in the AlertDialog, should I?